# how to send data from popover view controller to main view controller. Pass a string so that i can make that as the label text in the main view

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I tried many methods to send data from my popup view controller to main view controller. but failed. can anybody help me with this.
i am using a "present as popover" segue. i want to the text entered in textfield of popover view as the label text of main view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Popup View, Data send to  Main ViewController using protocol in Swift 3.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RmXx.png)
Complete Details are given below...
1. View Controller Implementing with Protocol named sendDataToViewProtocol.

```
import UIKit
 class ViewController: UIViewController,sendDataToViewProtocol {

 @IBOutlet weak var lshowDataLabel: UILabel!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
@IBAction func btnShowPopUpDialog(_ sender: Any) {
    let popUpVc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopupVIewController") as! PopupVIewController
    //Don't forget initialize protocal deletage
    popUpVc.delegate = self
    self.addChildViewController(popUpVc)
    popUpVc.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popUpVc.view)
    popUpVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

func inputData(data: String) {
    lshowDataLabel.text = data

}
}
```

2. Popup View Controller With Protocol named  sendDataToViewProtocol below.
   3.protocol declare outside the PopupVIewController.
3. Don't forget to assign ViewController to PopupVIewController .
4. In viewController withIdentifier: "PopupVIewController" , "PopupVIewController" is PopupVIewController storyborad Id.
5. Please see the attached image.

   ```
    import UIKit

    protocol sendDataToViewProtocol {
      func inputData(data:String)
    }

   class PopupVIewController: UIViewController {
   //Protocol object
    var delegate:sendDataToViewProtocol? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var txtInputFieldText: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor
    .black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
    }

    @IBAction func btnSendDataToViewController(_ sender: Any) {
    //"Check Delegate nil"
    if(delegate != nil){
        //Check textField is empty
       if(txtInputFieldText.text != ""){
           //set textField Data to protocol Function
           delegate?.inputData(data: txtInputFieldText.text!)
           self.view.removeFromSuperview()
       }

     }
    }

    @IBAction func btnClose(_ sender: Any) {
      self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much...nice explanation. thanks buddy.. I was stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep a temporary variable in your Main ViewController. Let's call it:
`var somethingCool: String?`

Then, in your popup ViewController code, assuming you have your segue trigger there, you will need to add in a new method.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "your_segue_identifier" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? MainViewController {
            vc.somethingCool = "whatever_you_want"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have made a segue from first view to second view. my segue identifier is popuversegue. from the first view controller if i press i button i have to go to second view controller. and from the second view controller i have to send the text entered in the text field to the first view with a button click